# How to subscribe to a Raspberry Pi Broker in a different network using Mosquitto MQTT?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, mosquitto

I did this project
https://diyi0t.com/microcontroller-to-raspberry-pi-wifi-mqtt-communication/
But in that project, the Raspberry Pi is both the Broker and Subscriber. I would like to Subscribe my Raspberry Pi at work, to my Raspberry Pi Broker at home.
I tried making my home Pi a static IP address, but it keeps timing out.

How can I connect from a different network? I just want to be able to run the Python code and receive the readings from the sensor that the Pi at home has.
Thank you.

Comment: So can your work RPi can ping your home RPi??  I am assuming that there is an Internet connection of some sort between the two, and that you have some sort of VPN to ensure a secure connection so that you have no reason to have a wide-open home network open to any hacker that comes along ;)

Comment: @JDAllen , I just made it work by forwarding port 1883 to the Pi, and subscribing with my public address...it works, but I feel it's extremely unsafe

Comment: It's only unsafe if you've not enabled any authentication/acl